# Get the average in a dataframe up to each observation

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I want to get the average score by Name going up to the date.

Here is an example dataframe

```
Date    Name  Score

1/1/16  Bill   5
1/1/16  Hank   5 
1/1/16  Aaron  10
1/2/16  Hank   15
1/2/16  Bill   10
1/3/16  Bill   20
1/3/16  Aaron  20
1/4/16  Aaron  20
```

How can I add this column?

```
Date    Name  Score Average_to_date

1/1/16  Bill   5     NA
1/1/16  Hank   5     NA
1/1/16  Aaron  10    NA
1/2/16  Hank   15    5
1/2/16  Bill   10    5
1/3/16  Bill   20    7.5
1/3/16  Aaron  20    10
1/4/16  Aaron  20    15
```

Comment: Use any of the methods from this question: [How to average column values by group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061), but wherever you see the function `mean` use `cummean` instead. It's surprising that you consider the average of a single number to be undefined - you might have to post-process to set the first value to `NA` if that's really necessary.

Comment: I do not consider the average of a simple number undefined. It is the average of 0 numbers. Thank you for the cummean comment.

Comment: You should describe want you wanted to the column to be then.  Just saying "How can I add this column?" could have completely validly gotten the answer `df[["Average_to_date"]] <- c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 7.5, 10, 15)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Average_to_date = lag(cummean(Score))
```

You can leave out the `arrange` if you are sure your data frame is already sorted by Date. Otherwise, please make sure your `Date` column is of `Date` class before arranging - see `?as.Date` for details.